# Run user-data script on EC2 infrastructure change

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, terraform

I recently created a Terraform module that deploys an EC2 instance and, upon launch, runs the user-data script, which downloads a docker image from ECR, and runs it.

I just noticed that upon changing the infrastructure (when changing the instance type from t2 to m5), the previously running Docker app stops, and the user-data script is not re-triggered.

I would like to know if it is possible, and how, to run the user-data script upon changing the infrastructure change.

Furthermore, I would also like to know if its possible to execute another script instead of the original user-data one, as I suspect it might be necessary to first kill the previous docker container.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What type of instance is this? IS it linux or Windows? If it's Linux then you should be able to `rm /var/lib/cloud/instances/*/sem/config_scripts_user` . This is the state files that are held to tell the userdata not to run as it's already been run before, if you remove this then next time you reboot it will run again.  Alternatively, when you change the instance size, if you change the userdata ever so slightly it will cause the Userdata to run again since it detects a state change from initial boot.

Comment: well apparently changing the user-data script triggers the termination of the previous instance, and the deployment of a new one. so technically it solves that problem hehe @Liam

Comment: Is Terraform reprovisioning the instance?  (I don't think you can change the instance type of an existing EC2 instance.)  Are you directly managing the instance, or is there an autoscaling group involved?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add this to your ec2 instance so that the userdata change does not trigger a new instance:

```
 lifecycle {
    # Prevent cross-platform terraform bug: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4954
    ignore_changes = ["user_data"]
  }
```